# httppost doesn't change the content type

Tags: java, http-post

This is my code:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postUrl);
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
StringEntity bodyEntity = new StringEntity("{\"name\":\"hello\"}");
bodyEntity.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
httpPost.setEntity(bodyEntity);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
String responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
System.out.println(responseString);
```

I keep getting the error `unsupported content type` though my web service just takes `json`, I checked the  httpPost content type and it is always `plain text`, why is it not changing to JSON please?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 public static void HttpPost() {
        try {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                    "https://api.website.net/auth/token");
            StringEntity input = new StringEntity("{\"name\":\"hello\"}");
            post.setEntity(input);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: how can this solve my problem? where is the content type?